# Why doesn't vasm6502's .org directive place the value at the expected address?

Tags: assembly, embedded, eeprom, 6502

Consider the following vasm6502 oldstyle code:

```
 .org $8000 ;Set the start address
 
 lda #%11111111 ;Prepare data all pins to output on PORTB
 sta %0110000000000010 ;Set all pins to output on PORTB
 
 lda #%10101010 ;Prepare data all pins high on PORTB
 sta %0110000000000000 ;Set all pins high on PORTB
 
 .org $fffc
 .word $8000
 .word $0000
```

Why does `.org $fffc` place **$8000** at **0x7ffc** and not at the **0xfffc** address?

[image]

Comment: Because the file starts at `$8000` so everything is offset by that amount. If you load this at `$8000` at runtime, the `$7ffc` will be correctly at `$fffc`

Comment: `org` isn't actually placed into your executable anywhere. It's just there so that the assembler can correctly translate your `JMP` and `JSR` operands to the correct addresses. The first `org` in your document isn't going to pad your file, but the others will.